# elastic beanstalk linux php GD library error on imagerotate

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been running the following imagerotate code on my MAMP and Lamp site for a long time (Lamp being on an AWS EC2 micro instance) with no issues.

```
...

case 6 :
// 90 rotate right
$destinationImage = imagerotate($destinationImage, -90, -1);
$this -> log -> lwrite('90 rotate right');
$this -> log -> lwrite(var_export($destinationImage, true));
break;

....
return imagejpeg($destinationImage, $destination, 100);
```

I've just migrated across to elastic beanstalk and deployed from git using eb tools and eb aws.push.

Since pushing this to ELB I'm seeing the following errors in my logs

```
PHP Warning:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/app/current/util/ImageUtil.class.php on line 221
```

This tells me that the imagerotate is not working for some reason and returning false. My normal logging pumps out:

```
[26/Apr/2014:09:34:15] (image_upload) [2-f9skfpbrbdi36kdvr42gh3tt71] : 90 rotate right
[26/Apr/2014:09:34:15] (image_upload) [2-f9skfpbrbdi36kdvr42gh3tt71] : false
```

Is this a known issue on elastic beanstalk? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

this was not necessarily an amazon bug.

I found the imagerotate call using -1 as below failed.

```
$destinationImage = imagerotate($destinationImage, -90, -1);
```

whereas the version using 0 worked

```
$destinationImage = imagerotate($destinationImage, -90, 0);
```